# FactoryGirl has_many, has_many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

**user.rb**

```
 has_many :company_users, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :companies, through: :company_users
```

**company_user.rb**

```
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user
```

**company.rb**

```
  has_many :company_users, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :company_users
```

How to write the FactoryGirl configuartion for company.

Whenever company is create company_user is also created with user_id and company_id field. How can I achieve this?

I'm not able to understand to get it.

Comment: There are [associations](http://rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Associations)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
factory :company do

  after(:build) do |company|
    company_users = build(:company_users, company: company)
    company.company_users << company_users
  end

end

factory :company_users do
  user
  company
end
```

Hope that's helpful.